# Why strokeColor for CAShapeLayer can't be with alpha component? It makes 2 different colored borders

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

adding my code. It's adding one more border with another alpha, like shadow.

```
let sliderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    sliderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    sliderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    sliderLayer.lineWidth = 20
    sliderLayer.miterLimit = 0.0
    sliderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    sliderLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:bounds.midY), radius: 190 / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    sliderLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens because of how the stroke is overlapping your fill color. When you give it a alpha of 0.5 you are letting the white show through at 50%, thus the red looks pink for half of your stroke. 50% red and 50% white = pink.

[image]

Here is a playground showing how to achieve a boarder with an alpha value. You need to use 2 circles and layer them to get the desired effect.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768)

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:200, y:200), radius: 190 / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        let redCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        redCircle.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        redCircle.path = bezierPath.cgPath

        let bezierPath2 = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath2.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x:200, y:200), radius: 170 / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        let whiteCircle = CAShapeLayer()
        whiteCircle.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        whiteCircle.path = bezierPath2.cgPath

        redCircle.addSublayer(whiteCircle)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(redCircle)
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but how to avoid this effect? i want to have just that 50% of red, without pink

Comment: Create 2 circles. Create a red circle that is as wide as the you want the circle to be with a fill color of 50% red. Then add a sublayer of another circle with a white color as the fill that is slightly smaller than the red circle